# how do I make django and tornado communicate with each other

Tags: django, rest, websocket, tornado

I have a social networking kinda an app in Django and I wanna integrate real-time notifications and messaging functionality in my app.

my friends could build a tornado app but I wanna basically connect them together (my guess are I have to make a REST API correct me if I'm wrong)

how can I do these kinda tasks from Django

- Authenticate automatically to a WebSocket(tornado) as I logged in my
  django app
- import all of my friends
- send tornado signal to send notifications if the user didn't receive a message

things like that

how do I do stuff like that.

(BTW I don't wanna use django channels as it's fairly new)

Comment: django-channels has been around for a few years now. It's been made into an official Django project. I think it's pretty stable. I think you should use it if you're looking to create a project quickly.

Comment: You can use Tornado and Django side-by-side. You'd have to use message queues and an in-memory db like Redis.  If you have time you can learn these technologies. It will help you in future. If you want to set up a project quickly, I don't think this is the way you want to go.

Comment: I believe in making things stable rather than getting it done quickly. This technique to use external framework has been around for a long time and I just don't have trust on channels. Also channels is not asynchronous, underneath it runs like a synchronize framework which is why I just don't want to get into this.

Comment: django-channels is asynchronous. Read the [FAQs](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faqs.html). Also, channels run in a separate process, so that is very similar to running an *"external framework"*. And, it is stable, whether you trust it or not. What I'm trying to say is, just for implementing real-time notifications there's no point in going through all the trouble of setting up Tornado alongside Django. Anyway, if you're really inclined to do so, look up `Message Queues` - that's how Tornado and Django can communicate.

Comment: I have been looking into channels since your last comment and I'm getting deep into it. I'll try implementing it using channels

Answer (score 0):

You can use a message broker library like ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ to help them communicate with each other (The Django instance and the Tornado websockets component).
They provide several message architectures like server-client or publisher-subscriber.